# how to run magento cron without cron installed ,manually

Tags: magento, cron

Manually running cron.php page will do cron job,

if not is there any other way to execute all cron scripts manually once a day
(we have back-end faculty to do it manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php -f cron.php` in magento root directory, or runc `./cron.sh` or create php file for run need task for example

```
<?php 
//Load Magento API
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

//First we load the model
$model = Mage::getModel('sap/cron_sync_nonimage');

//Then execute the task
$model->run();
```

sources this site http://catgento.com/2012/10/22/executing-cron-tasks-manually-in-magento/ but for secure this script will be created in folder `shell` for example `shell/mycron.php` and run this script you can by `php -f shell/mycron.php`.

And if you whant start standart job you can see to folder `shell`

> indexer.php run by `php -f indexer.php -- help` this shell indexing your catalog
>
> compiler.php run by `php -f compiler.php` this shell compiling your instance magento to one file.

and other files shell you can see this folder by command `ls -l shell/` and you need run this command in you magento root directory.

Answer (score 2):

you can execute via  a link like

```
    public function cronAction() {
    //First we load the model
    $model = Mage::getModel('clarion_reviewreminder/observer');
    //Then execute the task
    $model->sendReviewReminder();
}
```

run .../cron/ action

your tasks at the model will rull

Answer (score 2):

```
    public function cronAction() 
    {
       //First we load the model
       $model = Mage::getModel('clarion_reviewreminder/observer');
       //Then execute the task
       $model->sendReviewReminder();
    }
```

Comment: You may need to edit your code a bit because you didn't get the final `}` into the code block. It would also be helpful if you could explain what your code does.